# Getting indices of True values in a boolean list

Tags: python, list

I have a piece of my code where I'm supposed to create a switchboard. I want to return a list of all the switches that are on. Here "on" will equal `True` and "off" equal `False`. So now I just want to return a list of all the `True` values and their position. This is all I have but it only return the position of the first occurrence of `True` (this is just a portion of my code):

```
self.states = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]

def which_switch(self):
    x = [self.states.index(i) for i in self.states if i == True]
```

This only returns "4"

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Use `enumerate`, `list.index` returns the index of first match found.

```
>>> t = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(t) if x]
[4, 5, 7]
```

For huge lists, it'd be better to use `itertools.compress`:

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> list(compress(xrange(len(t)), t))
[4, 5, 7]
>>> t = t*1000
>>> %timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(t) if x]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.55 ms per loop
>>> %timeit list(compress(xrange(len(t)), t))
1000 loops, best of 3: 696 µs per loop
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I saw some similar questions telling me to use enumerate, but I guess I was using it wrong. I was setting the list equal to `x`,  then doing `enumerate(x)` but I guess all I was doing was enumerating 4? Is that what was happening? Thanks for the help

Comment: Also what is happening when you do `i for i, x` in the list comprehension? I'm only used to seeing `i for i` for example, or a similar format, what is the function of `x`? Thanks

Comment: @Amon `enumerate` returns a tuples(ind, value) during the loop, now we can assign the items of the tuple to two variables using: `i, x = (ind, value)`. This is exactly what is happening in that loop.

Comment: Oh I see what's happening now. Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: For anyone using Python3, in the `itertools.compress` solution, change the `xrange` to `range`. ( `xrange` was renamed to `range` in Python 3. )

Comment: Note: you can turn any list into this framework by simply adding to the condition `[ ... if x == condition]`. You don't have to start with a bool list.

Answer (score 91):

If you have numpy available:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> states = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>>> np.where(states)[0]
array([4, 5, 7])
```

Comment: Note that this returns a tuple which requires `np.where(states)[0]` to actually use the results

Answer (score 42):

**TL; DR**: use **`np.where`** as it is the fastest option. Your options are `np.where`, `itertools.compress`, and `list comprehension`.

See the detailed comparison below, where it can be seen **`np.where` outperforms both `itertools.compress` and also `list comprehension`**.

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]`
>>> t = 1000*t
```

- **Method 1: Using `list comprehension`**

```
>>> %timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(t) if x]
457 µs ± 1.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

- **Method 2: Using `itertools.compress`**

```
>>> %timeit list(compress(range(len(t)), t))
210 µs ± 704 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

- **Method 3 (the fastest method): Using `numpy.where`**

```
>>> %timeit np.where(t)
179 µs ± 593 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Love the benchmark!!!

Comment: I got different benchmark result. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71101281/11671779)

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter for it:

```
filter(lambda x: self.states[x], range(len(self.states)))
```

The `range` here enumerates elements of your list and since we want only those where `self.states` is `True`, we are applying a filter based on this condition.

For Python > 3.0:

```
list(filter(lambda x: self.states[x], range(len(self.states))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using element-wise multiplication and a set:

```
>>> states = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>>> set(multiply(states,range(1,len(states)+1))-1).difference({-1})
```

Output:
`{4, 5, 7}`

Comment: (1) return set, (2) complicated, (3) obscure, (4) very slow. Just don't use this, please. +1 for effort.

Comment: `multiply` is unclear, maybe you means `numpy.multiply`.

Answer (score 2):

I got different benchmark result compared to [@meysham answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630252/11671779). In this test, compress seems the fastest (python 3.7).

```py
from itertools import compress
import numpy as np
```

```py
t = [True, False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]

%timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(t) if x]
%timeit list(compress(range(len(t)), t))
%timeit list(filter(lambda x: t[x], range(len(t))))
%timeit np.where(t)[0]

# 2.54 µs ± 400 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 2.67 µs ± 600 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 6.22 µs ± 624 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# 6.52 µs ± 768 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```py
t = 1000*t
%timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(t) if x]
%timeit list(compress(range(len(t)), t))
%timeit list(filter(lambda x: t[x], range(len(t))))
%timeit np.where(t)[0]

# 1.68 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# 947 µs ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# 3.96 ms ± 97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# 2.14 ms ± 45.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary comprehension way,

```
x = {k:v for k,v in enumerate(states) if v == True}
```

Input:

```
states = [False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Output:

```
{4: True, 5: True, 7: True}
```

Comment: It's a dict-comprehension not list comprehension.

Comment: Why `dict` comprehension if you just need the key (indices)? All value is `True` anyway.  .___.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
def which_index(self):
    return [
        i for i in range(len(self.states))
        if self.states[i] == True
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution and welcome to StackOverflow. However, please read [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting, and also add some explanation to your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by using boolean mask array with square bracket, it's faster than `np.where`

```
>>> states = [True, False, False, True]
>>> np.arange(len(states))[states]
array([0, 3])
```

```
>>> size = 1_000_000
>>> states = np.arange(size) % 2 == 0
>>> states 
array([ True, False,  True, ..., False,  True, False])
>>> true_index = np.arange(size)[states]
>>> len(true_index)
500000
>>> true_index
array([     0,      2,      4, ..., 999994, 999996, 999998])
```