# Getting True values in a boolean list from indices - python

Tags: python, list

How do I compute the inverse of what is described here: [Getting indices of True values in a boolean list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448225/getting-indices-of-true-values-in-a-boolean-list) ?
That above link always comes up when I try searching for "how to obtain the true values in a boolean list from integer indices," but it gives me the indices from the true values in a boolean list, which is the inverse of what I want...

For example, from:

```
t = [4, 5, 7]
count = 16
```

I want to obtain:

```
[False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

The values are all 0 indexed, as expected with Python. 
I'm guessing that my question is a duplicate, but it's so annoying to not be able to find what I'm looking for every time I try to remember how to do this operation, I decided to ask a new question so my Google search will hopefully bring up this post next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension. I recommend you turn `t` into a `set` for O(1) lookup:

```
t_set = set(t)
res = [i in t_set for i in range(count)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension with conditions:

```
print([True if i in t else False for i in range(count)])
```

Shorter:

```
print([i in t else False for i in range(count)])
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
In [6]: holderplace =[False for i in range(count)]

In [7]: for i in t:
   ...:     holderplace[i-1]=True
   ...:     

In [8]: holderplace
Out[8]: 
[False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False]

In [9]:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
list(map(lambda x: x in t, range(count)))
# [False, False, False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

It might also be worth converting `t` to a set, since lookup is O(1) instead of O(N).

You could also use [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__):

```
list(map(t.__contains__, range(count)))
```