# Fast way of turning a list of indexes into a boolean mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

This is a really simple question but I've not found a simple answer. Say you have a large array, a list of indexes into that array, and you want to generate a boolean mask using those indexes.

```
import numpy as np

# A large array
arr = np.random.uniform(0., 1., 500000)

# A list of indexes (much larger in real code)
idx = [89, 3455, 3, 26789]

# The boolean mask
msk = []
for _ in range(len(arr)):
    if _ in idx:
        msk.append(True)
    else:
        msk.append(False)
msk = np.array(msk)
```

The for block above works, but gets slow for large `idx` arrays. What would be a fast way to achieve this? I know `np.where()` [can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630252/1391441) the other way around (boolean into indexes), can it be used here also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a much simpler way to do this using numpy zeros and the indexes.

```
msk = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
msk[idx] = True
```

It is efficient for large arrays

Comment: `np.bool` was deprecated in NumPy 1.20, the code raises AttributeError, you can use `bool` or `np.bool_`.